# How to close programs running in the background

Tags: sh, vi, ps

when I do `ps` I see `vi Dockerfile` running how do I close it?

I tried `q!` in the vi editor but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: check out [kill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)

Comment: see `man kill` and `man killall`. In this case, if you're not running any other processes called "vi" I would simply `killall vi`.

Comment: `killall vi` worked.

Comment: Did you mean `:q!` ? If not, try that. Best to learn you editor ;-) Good luck.

Comment: sorry `q!` editing mistake.

Comment: Use KILL<PID> Or killall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before killing the process like suggested in the comments, you could try to get it from the background to the foreground with the command `fg`.

After bringing it to the foreground you can close the program like you would normally do. In case of vi with:

- `:q` if you have no changes made to the file
- `:qw` if you have made changes and want to keep them
- `:q!` if you have made changes but don't want to keep them.

If `fg` doesn't work you can use `kill` or `killall` like suggested in the comments.

I prefer `kill`, because it only kills the process you choose.
Find process:

```
$ ps -ef | grep <e.g. program_name>
```

Example output:

```
user  15256 31598  0 14:41 pts/0    00:00:01 program_name
```

Kill process:

```
$ kill 15256
```